# Mixing overlapped IO and registered IO

Tags: windows, sockets

We are making experiments with the new registered IO interface.

In one experiment, we introduced the `WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED` in a pre-existing library in order to try a partial transition, like this:

```
SOCKET s = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, nullptr, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED);
```

This application uses completion ports and `AcceptEx()`. It succeeds in accepting connections when the target socket is initialized as above. We also verify the accepted socket is valid using it as target to `WSAIoctl()` calls.

After this change, calling `WSARecv()` on the accepted socket fails with error 10038 (`WSAENOTSOCK`).

If we take `WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED` from the initialization line, as above, everything works as expected. We are testing this on a Windows Server 2012 system.

Is there a way to use `WSARecv()` and `RIOSend()` on the same socket? Or is this intentionally forbidden?

Comment: Since you already have a completion port, use `RIOCreateCompletionQueue()` to register it for RIO completions, and then use `RIOReceive/Ex()` to perform the actual reads. You can't use `WSARecv()` with RIO.

Comment: @Remy, am I missing something or is `WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED_IO` not even documented?  I can't find a single mention on MSDN.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: While MSDN does document the individual RIO functions, it doesn't provide a high-level overview of how the RIO API actually works.  There are plenty of third-party websites that do, though. For instance, [Windows 8 Registered I/O Networking Extensions](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/10/windows-8-registered-io-networking-extensions.html).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: the functions are documented, but I can't find any mention of the flag.  In particular, the documentation for WSASocket doesn't say that `WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED_IO` is a valid flag.  Just an oversight, I suppose, but it seems worrying.